# Classname auto-completion in React css

Tags: css, reactjs

I found out that in ReactJS, there is no add-ons which auto-completes ClassNames while coding CSS File.

```
import './log-in.css';

function Login() {
  return <div className='LoginForm'>
       Hello World
    </div>
}

export default Login;
```

If we want to apply CSS tag into `LoginForm`, should we manually write down all ClassName? or is there any add-ons that I can use to have ClassName auto-completion.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below code to your VSCode Settings.json file. The settings.json will be found at `vscode setting -> Code Action on save -> Edit on Settings.json`

```
{
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact",
    "typescript": "typescriptreact"
},
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem